How to Configure Karpenter to Use Placement Groups in AWS EKS?
I'm using Karpenter for provisioning EC2 instances in my EKS cluster. My application requires that certain EC2 instances be launched within placement groups (e.g., for low-latency or high-throughput workloads).
Questions
How can I configure Karpenter to use placement groups when provisioning nodes?
Should this be configured in the EC2NodeClass, Provisioner, or somewhere else?
Is it possible to have different node groups use different placement groups (e.g., cluster placement group for compute-intensive workloads and spread placement group for general workloads)?
Karpenter version: latest
EKS k8s version: 1.31
I've looked into adding placement group configuration in the EC2NodeClass, but I'm not sure about the correct syntax or if it's even possible.

You need to create several NodePools. Then specify a label and a taint for the NodePool, like so:
apiVersion: karpenter.sh/v1beta1
kind: NodePool
metadata:
  name: nodepool-low-latency
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.schedule: low-latency
    spec:
      taints:
      - key: app.schedule
        value: "low-latency"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
      requirements:
      ...

After that, specify node selectors and tolerations for each workload so applications that are "low latency" will schedule on nodes that are under the low latency nodepool.
      tolerations:
      - key: "app.schedule"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "low-latency"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
      nodeSelector:
        app.schedule: low-latency

